# On an iPhone, how do you generate 15 decimal digits of entropy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random

I want to generate a random floating point number between `0.000000000000000` and `0.999999999999999`. I am using this code, but it doesn't generate that value I want:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{
    float num = (random() / (float) LONG_MAX) ;
    NSLog(@"Show Light:= %f",num);
}
```

What can I do to make this work? I have seen [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), but I didn't understand it properly.

Comment: Try to be more clear, and explain the real problem

Comment: I tried to edit your question so that it's possible to discern what you're asking. Please revise it further if I have changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: @PengOne i want value which is 0 point after value should be about 15 digits.like something 0.300000011920929 did you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of this sounds like a format string issue. You probably want something more like:

```
NSLog(@"Show Light:= %0.15lf", dbl);
```

Most people don't care about that many digits. ;-) (The `%lf` format assumes you'll change your `float` to a `double`.)

The other part is, I don't understand what the code you posted is trying to accomplish. Why are you calling `random()` 9 times? It seems to me that you would be better served populating the bits in the [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) yourself. You could set the sign and exponent bits, then use 52 bytes of `random()` for the exponent.

---

**Edit**: I think I was over-thinking this. This may not be the optimal solution, but I think it will work for your use case. Note that for 15 digits of random digits you need 50 bytes of random data, so we needed to use a 64-bit integer:

```
static uint64_t random64()
{
    uint64_t randomValue;
    randomValue = (random() | ((uint64_t) random() << 32));

    return randomValue;
}

static double getRandomDouble15Digits()
{
    double random15digits = random64() * 10e-15L;
    long wholeNumber = (long) random15digits;
    return (random15digits -= (double) wholeNumber);
}
```

... then multiply by 10 (to the power of -15) to get your 15 digits, and remove the whole number part of the fraction.

Comment: thnx.it work for me but after implementing i will check, bcoz i want to use this value in   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:Value target:self selector:@selector(dosomething:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];.

Comment: i have tried like this         NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.15lf",my double value];
        double temp = [tempStr doubleValue];
but this temp value is `0.277775` although i want this value in format `277774710803188` but this casting is not working.?!

Comment: @Hrushikesh, `%0.15lf` is the format string you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

the random function only generates a number between 0  and 2^31 which is a max of 10 digits.

if you want 15 digits you are going to have to call it a couple of times and do some concatenating to come up with 15

also given random returns a long integer, which given what you want to do with it, it seems pointless to convert it to a float. convert it to a string with a format from the link you provided, %ld if my memory serves me correctly.

sorry, the question has changed since I wrote this.  Float does not give you enough decimal points you are going to need to use double instead

Comment: by your answer i used like this double num = (random() / (double) LONG_MAX) ;  but it doesn't work as i expected it gives me values like this `0.277775` (for 0.up to 15 digits )still i can't get value as i expected.pls provide idea.